# reFind cannot see OSX; after repartitioning Macintosh HD

Tags: macbook-pro, efi

I had reFind working properly on a 2015 retina display mbp;

20gb Linux Mint partition and the remaining 440~gb for OSX,

wanted to install Win10 on a third 50gb partition,

repartitioned Macintosh HD for new 50gb cut out,

installed Windows 10,

fixed boot load order in Windows 10,

The boot manager rEFInd now only sees Linux Mint, Windows 10 and a (legacy) Windows 10 option. No longer recognizes OSX or OSX (legacy) that was there prior.

Here is my `fdisk` in Linux Mint:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.9 GiB, 500277790720 bytes, 977105060 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D3C3E48A-C276-42E1-95AC-73F50AF36DC7

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type 
/dev/sda1         40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2     409640 829644079 829234440 395.4G unknown
/dev/sda3  829644800 829677567     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4  829677568 928276479  98598912    47G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  928276896 976842879  48565984  23.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  976842880 977105023    262144   128M unknown
```

Comment: Does Mint include the `gdisk` command? Do you know which version of macOS you have installed? Do you know if the macOS partition was using Core Storage or APFS?

Comment: Mint does include gdisk, it was running Mojave and I did an update very recently (this week); it was using APFS, as when I created the new partition, it spent a while 'resizing APFS storage,' I think was the comment in the disk utility window.